# Laravel could not find driver (Connection: mysql

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I get the below error when running php artisan migrate for the first time.
I have setup a Mariadb container which is running properly but laravel is unable to find it.

Extensions installed: pdo_mysql, mysqli

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        networks:
            - laravel
            - dbnet
    mariadb:
        container_name: mariadb
        image: mariadb:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        environment:
            MARIADB_DATABASE: laravel
            MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
        networks:
            - dbnet
            - laravel
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official PHP runtime as a parent image
FROM php:8.3.2-fpm

# Set the working directory to /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        unzip

# Install Xdebug
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions xdebug zip pdo_mysql mysqli @composer

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

# Install Laravel dependencies using Composer
RUN composer install
rt 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]rt 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Running `php artisan migrate`:

> could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravel' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)
> Context: {"exception":{"errorInfo":null,"connectionName":"mysql"}}

at vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:137

env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

config.database

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
],
```

Comment: You're positive PHP MySQL extension is installed? --> run a `phpinfo()` and check that the extension is not only is installed, but it's enabled in PHP

Comment: Command line: `php -r "phpinfo();"`

Comment: @Zak pdo_mysql, mysqli and mysqlnd are installed and enabled in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was related to how I was executing the php artisan command inside the Docker container.
It was executed from a shell script outside of the containers, leading to the mentioned error.

Executing the command directly inside the Docker container worked.